# JS function only plays once (until refreshed)

Tags: javascript

This is the js I used:

```
var bgcolor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

function changeBackground() {
   document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
}
```

And the HTML for the button:

```
<button onclick="changeBackground();">
```

The function works, however, it only works once and then does not work again until I refresh the page. I am new to js, is there something I might be missing or doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: bgcolor is only set once, so it only runs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try this

js

```
function changeBackground() {
   var bgcolor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
   document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
}
```

html

```
<button onclick="changeBackground();">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `bgcolor` variable once, after that it never changes. Move the setting inside the `changeBackground` function, and it should work.

```
function changeBackground() {
    var bgcolor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a number to bgcolor only once outside of your function. Try calling that line of code within the function itself, like so:

```
function changeBackground() {
    document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
    var bgcolor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bgcolor is in the global scope and calculated once at page start. Insert bgcolor var inside changeBackground function body so its value will be recalculated.